# how to use AngularJS routes with Haml templates in a Rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4

I have app/assets/templates/api-list.haml that I want to use as an AngularJS template. I followed [this tutorial](http://minhajuddin.com/2013/04/28/angularjs-templates-and-rails-with-eager-loading) to create a templates.js file that inserts all my compiled Haml AngularJS templates into `$templateCache`. However, I can't seem to make these cached templates work with my AngularJS routes:

```
api_app.config(['$routeProvider', ($routeProvider) ->
  $routeProvider.when '/',
    templateUrl: 'api-list'
    controller: api_app.ApiListController
  $routeProvider.otherwise
    redirectTo: '/'
])
```

When I load my app, I see a 404 error in the browser console because it tried to do a request to `http://localhost:3000/api-list`. I can look at /assets/templates.js in the browser and see that `$templateCache.put("api-list"` is defined, so there should be a template called "api-list". I am loading templates.js in my page before defining routes.

I also tried injecting `$templateCache` in my route config like so:

```
api_app.config(['$routeProvider', ($routeProvider, $templateCache) ->
  $routeProvider.when '/',
    template: $templateCache.get('api-list')
    controller: api_app.ApiListController
  $routeProvider.otherwise
    redirectTo: '/'
])
```

This causes an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined from ApiApp` error though. If I change the first line to `api_app.config(['$routeProvider', '$templateCache', ($routeProvider, $templateCache) ->`, I instead get the error `Uncaught Error: Unknown provider: $templateCache from ApiApp`.

How can I convince my routes to use the template from `$templateCache` instead of trying to load it via a new request?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got something working without `$templateCache`. I made a config/initializers/haml.rb file with the following:

```
Rails.application.assets.register_engine '.haml', Tilt::HamlTemplate
```

Then in my config/application.rb, I added `config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'templates')`.

I also renamed my template file from `api-list.haml` to `api-list.html.haml`. My routes look like this now:

```
api_app.config(['$routeProvider', ($routeProvider) ->
  $routeProvider.when '/',
    templateUrl: '/assets/api-list.html'
    controller: api_app.ApiListController
  $routeProvider.otherwise
    redirectTo: '/'
])
```

I don't like having `/assets` hard-coded in there, so I may end up changing this file from routes.js.coffee to routes.js.erb and using Rails helpers to get a path.

Comment: You could just make the file `routes.js.coffee.erb` to use coffeescript as well as use a rails helper

Answer (score 3):

The reason you were having trouble with templateCache is that routes are in a config block. If you refer to the AngularJS documentation about [modules](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module), you will see the following line:

> Only providers and constants can be injected into configuration blocks. This is to prevent accidental instantiation of services before they have been fully configured.